# Timer that is triggering an Alarm After 35 seconds

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

I Need an Timer, that's declared as NSTimer to triger a Alarm. I created all neidend Filets in the Vector.h (my ViewController.h). I'm trief that:

```
If(Timer == 35)
{Alert =[[ UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"end" Message: nil ....]}

 Else 

 {

  }
```

But it doesn't work! Please Help!

Benedict

Comment: you should add some more details .. for example how is Timer defined? You may want to look into NSTimer and its documentation since your code doesn't look like it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you have the sam problem as I had. You want to start the alert after X seconds, or? Is that what you mean? If Yes, then here is the solution! Regards Julian!

Do that in the ViewController.M

```
 -(IBAction)Start:(id)sender
{
Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30 target:self selector:@selector(alertStart)    userInfo:nil repeats:NO];


}


-(void) alertStart
 {

Alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"end" message: nil   delegate:self       cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];


// Above the Setup the Alert

[Alert show];
[Timer invalidate];
Timer = nil;
}
```